# NodeJs and MySQL ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I have a problem I need help with a question. So the problem is I have a route to display all rows of my students table and it works, but know when I try the code below to search for a specific student_id I get:

"Failed to query for users: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'"

I have tried the queryString as:
My table has student_id, firstName, lastName, checkIn, and checkOut as columns.
They are all VARCHARS.

queryString = `SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = ${id}`

queryString = `SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = ?` and then getConnection().query(queryString, [id], (err, rows, fields) => {

But I get the same error, I would really appreciate the help.
The question that I have would be implementing after all my different search routes work as intended to display the data nicely in html, but I'm new to this and I can't find anything to help me with this problem. I would like it to display as a list almost like MySQL displays it. Is that possible? I'm using the ejs view engine as my html pages.

```
// Route to search by id
router.get("/searchById", (req, res) => {

  const id = req.body.id

  queryString = `SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = ${id}`

  getConnection().query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {

    // If error occures 
    if(err) {
      console.log("Failed to query for users: " + err)
      res.sendStatus(500)
      return
    } 

    if(rows) {
      console.log(rows)
       console.log("We fetched Students successfully")
        res.json(rows)
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body.id` is defined? Try `console.log(req.body.id)`, what is the output?

Comment: Never use user-supplied data, like `req.body.id`, directly in SQL queries. Make sure the data [gets escaped properly](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: Did you try to add quote the the field name like where 'student_id' = and use double quote for the entire query

Comment: Ok, I figured it out req.body.id didn't work because the form was a GET and not POST. Is it okay to use POST even if I'm not posting anything?

Comment: Hi @Steven, can you please update the question about your findings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GET request you should use `req.query.id`
For post request you should use `req.body.id`
In your code you have used get request and tried to fetch `req.body.id`